# Change and replace function

Tags: filter, addition

Whatever I do, the test1 function does not change

`function test1(){ echo 'aaa'; } function test2() { echo 'bbb'; } add_filter( 'test1', 'test2', 10); test1();`

When I use add_filter, shouldn't "test2" replace "test1"?